# Excel Multiple Word Replacement in String

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, excel

GoodDay to you all!

I am working on an excel project and I am looking for some help. I don't mind whether this is solved via a formula or a script.

To begin with I will provide the big picture. I have a whole bunch of SQL Queries that call on various fields from different locations. These field titles have now changed. I would like to update the SQL Queries with the new names of the fields. As such, I was going to copy all the queries into an excel spreadsheet and then lookup the field names in the string and replace them with the new field names from a table in another sheet. The problem is that there is approximately 10 field names per query that need replacing.

So this is what I was thinking. Essentially, if I have a string in cell A1 with the words: "We are the very best". For every word that exists in the string I would like to check if it exists in a table in another sheet. If the word exists in the table, replace it. If not then move onto the next word. Continue for every word in the cell.

Any help that can be provided is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I take it the replacement word is defined in the other sheet?

Comment: Yeah, the replacement words will be defined in the other sheet. I would have column A with the originals and column B with the new words.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub FixIt()
    Dim r As Range, A As Range
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set A = s1.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In A
        v = " " & r.Value & " "
        For j = 1 To 10
            oldv = " " & s2.Cells(j, 1).Text & " "
            newv = " " & s2.Cells(j, 2).Text & " "
            v = Replace(v, oldv, newv)
        Next j
        r.Value = Trim(v)
    Next r
End Sub
```

In this example the replacement table is in Sheet2, cells A1 thru B10...............I pad with "spaces" to insure whole word replacement and to avoid the need to **Split** and **Join**.